# Neo4j SDN - OGM nodes equality

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a problem with Spring Data Neo4j and OGM. When I create a node for first time, it`s ok but if I refresh that page I get this error:

> Cypher execution failed with code 'Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintValidationFailed': Node(126) already exists with label `Country` and property `name` = 'Country-1'.

I searched the web and read so many documents about `equals` and `hashCode` but none of them is helping. Here are my classes:

```
public abstract class Place {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
    private String id ;

    private String name ;

    public String getId(){return id ;}

}

@Getter
@Setter
@NodeEntity(label = "Country")
@CompositeIndex(unique = true , properties = "name")
public class Country extends Place {

    private String label = "Country";

    public Country() {}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result  = label == null ? 1 : label.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + this.getName() == null ? 0 : this.getName().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + this.getId() == null ? 0 : this.getId().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Country)) {
            return false;
        }
        Country that = (Country) o ;
        return this.getName().equals(that.getName())
                && this.getId().equals(that.getId())
                && this.getLabel().equals(that.getLabel());
    }
}
```

Repository is default. As I know it`s a problem of equality check but how can I fix this?

Comment: hey is there any other classes in your project which are extending Places Class.

Answer (score 1):

You created a constraint on your `Country` entity by defining

`@CompositeIndex(unique = true , properties = "name")`

and probably you also enabled the auto index manager feature in the Neo4j-OGM `SessionFactory` configuration.
This is not related to any implementation of `hashCode` or `equals`.

This will also explain the behaviour you are facing: First run succeeds but the very same action repeated failed.

Comment: with this 
@CompositeIndex(unique = true , properties = "name")
i become sure to that node is not Created again , if i remove this , same node created in db every time , i refresh the page ,

i want way to ogm detect that is the same node !

Comment: In this case I need more information what happens when you "refresh the page". Controller / Service / repository calls or similar.

Comment: @FarjamRamezanpour did you read, change and write the `Country` node within the same session/transaction?